# iOS MediaRecorder - Record Video Via Camera Through MediaRecorder and HTML5 Video

Tags: html, ios, iphone, typescript, mediarecorder

**Issue:**

- Can't record video or get a video stream from the camera on iOS through my web application, this is running angular and build via `ng build`

**Investigation:**

- Reviewed various websites relating to Apple iOS `websockets`, `MediaRecorder`, and `getUserDevices()`
- Also spec and version supported specs. all docs I found say that the `MediaRecorder` is an experimental feature and needs to be enabled manually.

**Other:**

- My code works fine on Android Chrome, Desktop Chrome, Opera (PC/Mobile), and on firefox (PC/Mobile)

Sadly I'm not sure what to do. since the docs say that iOS doesn't support the recording API.

- My site is using https with valid certificates.

Any tips, links, resources, or code would be appreciated.

Comment: please help. thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've come across the answer to your issue already.

With your current implementation, you are not going to be able to support Safari or ANY iOS browser (they are all Webkit/Safari under the hood).

https://caniuse.com/?search=MediaRecorder

There are flags you can enable to make it work, but this is not something that you can generally ask your customers to do :)

Doug

Answer (score 2):

### 2022 MediaRecorder for IOS

As of Safari 14.5 you can use MediaRecorder API.
Here is a working example using MediaRecorder and `getUserMedia()`.

```
    startIOSVideoRecording: function() {
        console.log("setting up recorder");
        let self = this;
        this.data = [];

        if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/mp4')) {
            // IOS does not support webm! So you have to use mp4.
            var options = {mimeType: 'video/mp4', videoBitsPerSecond : 1000000};
        } else {
            // video/webm is recommended for non IOS devices
            console.error("ERROR: Is this really an IOS device??");
            var options = {mimeType: 'video/webm'};
        }

        // this has to be a canvas element (not video!)
        let stream = document.getElementById('self-canvas').captureStream(15);
        this.recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);

        this.recorder.ondataavailable = function(evt) {
            if (evt.data && evt.data.size > 0) {
                self.data.push(evt.data);
                console.log('chunk size: ' + evt.data.size);
            }
        }

        this.recorder.onstop = function(evt) {
            console.log('recorder stopping');
            var blob = new Blob(self.data, {type: "video/mp4"});
            // do something with the blob
        }
        this.recorder.start(1000);
        looper();
    },
```

Keep in mind that IOS still does not support `video.captureStream()` or `video/webm` at all, so you will need to set up a video element to connect the `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` and a canvas element for the MediaRecorder.
Also (on IOS) you can only declare one and only one `getUserMedia()` stream at a time! So it is best to make the video element or the stream global with `this.video` or `this.localStream` in case other elements want to access the stream.

```
this.localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: false,
    video: {width: 430, height: 430, facingMode: "user"}
});

let self = this;
self.video = document.createElement('video');
self.video.srcObject = this.localStream;
const canvas = document.getElementById("self-canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function draw_2DCanvas(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(self.video, 0, 0, 430, 430);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(draw_2DCanvas);
}
draw_2DCanvas();
```

On any other device you can just use `video.captureStream()` without having to go though the pain of setting up a canvas element.
Also `video/webm` is recommended in general.

**Important Note**
If you do not plan to edit the video in any way, directly passing the `localStream` to the MediaRecorder will also work, and it will also allow you to record the user's audio.

```
this.recorder = new MediaRecorder(this.localStream, options);
```

Comment: thanks bro, but solved this issue 2 years ago